# Correct way to invoke Task that void

Tags: c#, async-await, class-library

I am wanting to check to make sure that I am invoking methods that return void when a method only returns `Task` and not `Task<T>`.

I've got a helper method that it's signature looks like this:

```
internal async static Task DrawLeafMidrail(Graphics dc, float totalHeightFeet,    List<HorizontalContainer> horizontals, bool showDetails, bool showVerticalDetails)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                float y, sl, startX, endX, stileWidth = 0, btmRailPx = 0, leftJmb;
                PointF[] points;
                List<VerticalContainer> verticals = new List<VerticalContainer>();
                List<LineContainer> lines = new List<LineContainer>();

                //..code omitted
            });
        }
```

And I am calling this helper method of Task like:

```
Horizontal.DrawLeafMidrail(
                           dc, doorPoints.BayRect.Height / Constants.PIXELS_PER_FOOT,
                           lstHors, ,forDoorDetail).Wait();
```

Notice that I've got `.Wait()` appended to the end of the caller. I just want to make sure that this is the correct way and this will have the same effect as if the caller was to call the helper method like:

```
Task t = Horizontal.DrawLeafMidrail(dc, doorPoints.BayRect.Height / Constants.PIXELS_PER_FOOT, lstHors, i == 0, forDoorDetail);
t.Wait();
```

Comment: There's no reason for the first method to be `async`.  Just `return` the task created by `Task.Run` in a method not marked as `async`.  It'll do exactly the same thing, but won't have all of the overhead that `async` adds to a method.  And of course, you generally shouldn't be doing a blocking wait on a task, you should just be adding continuations (possibly through `await`).

Comment: @Servy Actually, in this case, the behavior is likely to be different, though not in a good way. With `await`, the `Wait()` is likely to cause a deadlock, while with your suggestion, it would work correctly (if you consider blocking a thread to be correct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wanting to check to make sure that I am invoking methods that return void when a method only returns Task and not Task.

This part of the question doesn't make sense.

> I just want to make sure that this is the correct way and this will have the same effect

Will it have the same effect? Yes. `Task` does not change expression evaluation, operator precedence, or how local variables behave.

Is it correct? No. You should be using `await`. Otherwise, you [could deadlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), as I explain in my MSDN article.

Comment: To the first point, see my edit, he didn't use code formatting properly.

Comment: Great answers, I've printed out the blog post and going to read that along with these answers.

Comment: @Stephen, Great article man! I've got a little better grip on this now. "Little".Anyway, what I've was doing was just automatically wrapping the entire body of a method, mostly helpers that return nothing / kind of like fire and forget. So, now I've removed that Task.Run() that was wrapping the entire method body and now placing await in from of the helper method and appending the .ConfigureAwait(False) because I do not care what goes on after I invoke that helper.So basically where I was off loading the workload that was already async Task I kept them that way and place the await where called

Comment: Basically, In one of the main function where I would line up the helpers one after another there was no need to wrap all the helpers in  a Task.Run(). The one area that I did not get was about the SemaphoreSlim mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1). In a way it seemed like there should be a way to pass a state object.